# laravel Job / Queue not been processed weird infinite loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I'm trying to create a queue but it doesn't work when I run `php artisan queue:work` all I get in my terminal is

```
[2017-11-30 19:56:27] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessCSV
[2017-11-30 19:56:27] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessCSV
[2017-11-30 19:56:27] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessCSV
[2017-11-30 19:56:27] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessCSV
[2017-11-30 19:56:27] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessCSV
[2017-11-30 19:56:27] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessCSV
[2017-11-30 19:56:27] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessCSV
[2017-11-30 19:56:27] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessCSV
[2017-11-30 19:56:27] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessCSV
[2017-11-30 19:56:27] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessCSV
```

It's like an infinite loop. The id in my jobs table just goes up and up too. It does work on my laptop but not on my desktop which is very strange. I put in onto my devleopment server and it doesn't work on there either.

My code is below and any help would be appreciated.

Controller

```
public function upload(Request $request) {
        if($request->file('imported-file')) {

            $user = "craig@boldy.co.uk";

            $file = $request->file('imported-file')->store('uploads', 'public');
            $this->dispatch(new ProcessCSV($file, $user));

            Session::flash('success', 'Your file was uploaded successfully. We will email you once the locations have be imported.');
            return back();

        } else {

            Session::flash('error', 'Please select a file to upload!!!!');
            return back();

        }

    }
```

Job

```
public function handle()
    {

        $data = Excel::load($this->file, function($reader) {})->get();

        $apiKey = '';

        foreach($data as $row) {

            if(!empty($row['postcode'])) {

                $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".urlencode($row['postcode'])."&region=uk&key=";
                $tmp = file_get_contents($url);
                $xml = simplexml_load_string($tmp);

                // print_r($xml); exit;

                if((string)$xml->status == 'OK' && isset($xml->result[0])) {

                    if(isset($xml->result[0]->geometry->location->lat)) {
                        $lat = (string)$xml->result[0]->geometry->location->lat;
                    }

                    if(isset($xml->result[0]->geometry->location->lng)) {
                        $lng = (string)$xml->result[0]->geometry->location->lng;
                    }

                }

                Import::updateOrCreate(
                    [
                        'sitecode' => $row['sitecode']
                    ],
                    [
                        'sitecode' => $row['sitecode'],
                        'sitename' => $row['sitename'],
                        'address_1' => $row['address_1'],
                        'address_2' => $row['address_2'],
                        'address_town' => $row['address_town'],
                        'address_postcode' => $row['postcode'],
                        'charity' => $row['charity'],
                        'latitude' => $lat,
                        'longitude' => $lng,
                        'approved' => 1
                    ]
                );

            }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

instead of `php artisan queue:work`..you need to add option param `--tries` to avoid infinite looping.. it usually occurred if error happen in job. see laravel.log or failed-job table if using driver database. it will show the error

```
php artisan queue:work --tries=3
```

Comment: I wonder why there is no default number of tries. It seems like a major screw up at first and then you realise there is a syntax error and you forgot to add tries.